# org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin : same file , multiples results

Tags: java, git, maven, plugins, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm using the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` in version 0.12.3, 
and I have the following problem.

1. I generate a java files from an xsd files.
2. I commit and push it on our git repository.
3. I launch the same generation again (we use `removeOldOutput` option).
4. For some file, git is detecting some changes, because the order of some annotations is not the same between 2 generations.

A part of the first generation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Software", propOrder = {
    "rest"
})
public abstract class Software
    extends SoftwareResource
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "resource", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "software", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "swapSpaceUsedCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "isUTCTime", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "lastStartTime", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "serialNumber", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "numberProcessesActiveCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "pagingFileSizeCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "processMemorySizeCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "numUsersCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> rest;

    /**
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Resource }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BigInteger }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Software }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Boolean }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BigInteger }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Quantity }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BigInteger }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Quantity }{@code >}
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> getRest() {
        if (rest == null) {
            rest = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>>();
        }
        return this.rest;
    }

}
```

The same part of the second generation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Software", propOrder = {
    "rest"
})
public abstract class Software
    extends SoftwareResource
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "numUsersCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "serialNumber", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "processMemorySizeCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "swapSpaceUsedCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "pagingFileSizeCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "lastStartTime", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "numberProcessesActiveCurrent", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "resource", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "isUTCTime", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "software", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    protected List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> rest;

    /**
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BigInteger }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Quantity }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link String }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Quantity }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BigInteger }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link BigInteger }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Boolean }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Resource }{@code >}
     * {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link Software }{@code >}
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>> getRest() {
        if (rest == null) {
            rest = new ArrayList<JAXBElement<? extends Serializable>>();
        }
        return this.rest;
    }

}
```

Why this annotations are ordered differently between 2 generations ? Is there a way to order them ?

Thanks !

Comment: Usually the generated sources aren't committed into version control.

Answer (score 1):

Author of the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` here.

First, Aleksandr M is perfectly right. Generated code is normally not checked into SCM. The whole `target` directory has nothing to do in `git`.

Next, the JAXB schema compiler (XJC) which is called by the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` is not deterministic, therefore the generated source code is not guaranteed to be identical between different code generations. This is definitely not an issue in the `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and I also won't call it a bug in XJC. Just lower your expectations, don't expect identical code between runs.